# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline that Satisfy ALL, one value and multi-value option to run multiple stages

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Requirement:

Jenkins pipeline example that can accept multiple release values and an ALL option
let's consider pipeline has 4 stages stage1 then stage 2 then stage3 and then stage 4 each is dependent on previous only to complete
ex: ALL, 1,2,3,4,5
When we choose ALL, all 4 stages should run in parallel for 1,2,3,4,5
when we choose anyone for ex: 3 then all 4 stages should run in parallel for 3
we also should be able to multiple release values, example: 3 and 5 in this all 4 stages should run in parallel for 3 and 5

I tried matrix, and it's working for ALL options but not for selective, so I had to write duplicate stages for individual ones like below.

But it doesn't support choosing multiple VERSION values, and code is not re-used effectively. Need help with code refactor to run it for multiple options and in parallel.

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    
    parameters {
        string(
            name: 'BRANCH',
            defaultValue: '',
            description: '...')
        choice(
            name: 'VERSION',
            choices: ["ALL", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
            description: 'Select version(s) for cluster deploy')
    }
    stages {
        stage('New Cluster') {
            when { expression { params.VERSION == "ALL" } }
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'BASE_VERSION'
                        values "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" 
                    }
                }
                Stages {
                    stage (1){
                        ...
                    }
                    stage (2) {
                        ...
                    }
                    stage (n) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Desired Version Cluster') {
            when {
                expression {
                    params.VERSION != "ALL"
                }
            }
            Stages {
                stage (1){
                    ...
                }
                stage (2) {
                    ...
                }
                stage (n) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```